# Regular expression not capturing optional group

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regular expression pattern:

```
.*(?<line>^\s*Extends\s+#(?<extends>[_A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*$)?.*
```

And the following text:

```
   Name                #asdf
   Extends             #extendedClass
   Origin              #id
```

What I don't understand is that both of the caught group results (line and extends) are empty, but when I remove the last question mark from the expression the groups are caught.

The line group must be optional since the Extends line is not always present.

I created a fiddle using this expression, which can be accessed at https://regexr.com/4rekk

EDIT

I forgot to mention that I'm using the multiline and dotall flags along with the expression.

Comment: You are using `.*` it captures all.

Comment: Combining tailing and leading `.*` with `^` and `$` and with `/s` and `/m` flags makes me feel that you are not fully aware of what you are exactly doing. So, what exactly is your goal?

Comment: Sorry, the tailing and leading .* are there because this was a part of a larger expression. My goal is to get "extendsClass" into the <extends> group and the whole line into the <line> group.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

It's already been mentioned that the leading `.*` is capturing everything when you make your `(?<line>)` group optional. The following is not directly related to your question *but it may be useful information* (if not, just ignore):

You need to be careful elsewhere. You are using `^` and `$` to match the start and end of lines as well as the start and end of the string. But the `$` character will not consume the newline character that marks the end of a line. So:

`'Line 1\nLine 2'.match(/^Line 1$^Line 2/m)` returns `null`

while

`'Line 1\nLine 2'.match(/^Line 1\n^Line 2/m)` returns a match

So in your case if you were trying to capture all three lines, any of which were optional, you would write the regex for one of the lines as follows to make sure you consume the newline:

```
/(?<line>^\s*Extends\s+#(?<extends>[_A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\S\n]*\n)?/ms
```

Where you had specified `\s*$`, I have `[^\S\n]*\n`.  `[^\S\n]*` is a double negative that says one or more **non** non-white space character excluding the newline character. So it will consume all white space characters except the newline character.  If you wanted to look for any of the three lines in your example (any or all are optional), then the following code snippet should do it. I have used the `RegExp` function to create the regex so that it can be split across multiple lines. Unfortunately, it takes a string as its argument and so some backslash characters have to be doubled up:

```js
let s = `   Name                #asdf
   Extends             #extendedClass
   Origin              #id
`;


let regex = new RegExp(
    "(?<line0>^\\s*Name\\s+#(?<name>[_A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\\S\\n]*\\n)?" +
    "(?<line>^\\s*Extends\\s+#(?<extends>[_A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\\S\\n]*\\n)?" +
    "(?<line2>^\\s*Origin\\s+#(?<id>[_A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\\S\\n]*\\n)?",
    'm'
);


let m = s.match(regex);
console.log(m.groups);
```

The above code snippet seems to have a problem under Firefox (an invalid regex flag, 's', is flagged on a line that doesn't exist in the above snippet). See the [following regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mEfXn4/1/).

And without named capture groups:

```js
let s = `   Name                #asdf
   Extends             #extendedClass
   Origin              #id
`;


let regex = new RegExp(
    "(^\\s*Name\\s+#([_A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\\S\\n]*\\n)?" +
    "(^\\s*Extends\\s+#([_A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\\S\\n]*\\n)?" +
    "(^\\s*Origin\\s+#([_A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\\S\\n]*\\n)?",
    'm'
);


let m = s.match(regex);
console.log(m);
```

Comment: When I run the snippet, I got: `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s",`

Comment: @Toto Yes, it seems to fail under Firefox with an error on a line that doesn't exist in the above snippet. It runs in Chrome and Node. It fails even if I remove the named groups. Unfortunately, the `s` flag is needed (the `m` flag is superfluous). 
 I've added a regex demo. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the named capture groups are not supported.

Comment: @Toto Yes, but even without them I was getting the same error (???). I added another snippet without them and you can try this on Firefox.

Comment: The `/s` flag (dot matches newline) is not supported and is useless here because you don't have any dot in the regex. You have to use `[\s\S]` or, better (for javascript) `[^]` to simulate “dot matches newline”.

Comment: One more comment, the question wasn't tagged `javascript` ;)

Comment: @Toto Right! See my comment 3 comments up. I can't believe I was getting flags `m` and `s` backwards.

Comment: @Toto It was tagged anything. It certainly wasn't Python.